# Правильный ли синтаксис php кода

Tags: php

Увидел в интернете такую строчку кода:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('[https://example.com/?'];. $get_params));
```

Разве это правильно? Ведь `file_get_contents` не работает с `https`. Да и что это такое: `'[`, `'];` ?

Comment: С https оно то работает (может не работать, если php так сконфигурировать). Но вот с кавычками похоже беда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file_get_contents отлично работает с https, за исключением одного частного случая, который описан в документации.

> При использовании SSL, Microsoft IIS нарушает протокол, закрывая
>   соединение без отправки индикатора close_notify. PHP сообщит об этом
>   как "SSL: Fatal Protocol Error" в тот момент, когда вы достигнете
>   конца данных. Чтобы обойти это, вы должны установить error_reporting
>   на уровень, исключающий E_WARNING. PHP версий 4.3.7 и старше умеет
>   определять, что на стороне сервера находится проблемный IIS при
>   открытии потока с помощью обертки https:// и не выводит
>   предупреждение. Если вы используете fsockopen() для создания ssl://
>   сокета, вы сами отвечаете за определение и подавление этого
>   предупреждения.

По поводу

```
'[https://example.com/?'];. $get_params
```

То тут на лицо синтаксическая ошибка, должно быть так

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://example.com/?'. $get_params));
```